# Paging display row numbers continually

Tags: php

So I have this page where i use paging. No problem with that but I want to display the row number. I display 25 records per page. You know page 1, 1-25, page 2, 26-50 and so on. But with this piece of code it starts over when you change page. Any tips?

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
$perPage = 25;
$startIndex = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;


<? $i = 1; foreach($db->query("SELECT value FROM pskills ORDER BY value DESC") as $row): ?>
#<?=$i?>. <?=$row['value']?>

<? $i++; endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Maybe because you're always selecting the same records from the database...?!

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs `LIMIT`

```
SELECT value FROM pskills ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT $startIndex , $perPage
```

Answer (score 0):

you need LIMIT and OFFSET

if you one page 25records

this the query for page 1

```
SELECT value FROM pskills ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

this the query for page 2

```
SELECT value FROM pskills ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25
```

this the query for page 3

```
SELECT value FROM pskills ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 50
```

and so on... add 25 every page

hope this query help you

Comment: actually can use logic and class and function.. even have 1.000.000.000 pages is also mo problem... i'm using those for paging...

Answer (score 0):

It will probably start over when you change page you need this query

```
 ($db->query("SELECT value FROM pskills where value > '.(pageno * 25).' ORDER BY value asc limit 25")
```

where pageno starts from 0 and so one. What it will do as

```
 1st page =====  value > (0*25)  result will be 1 to 25
 2nd page =====  value > (1*25)  result will be 25 to 50
 3rd page =====  value > (2*25)  result will be 50 to 75
```

I don't why you use order by desc? you want result from 1 - 25 then it should be asc.